# Error: Invalid version: "1.0" in node.js packge.json file

Tags: node.js, express, dependencies

I created a very basic `package.json` and running `npm install` is throwing version error.

**Erroneous package.json**

```
{
    "name": "appone",
    "description": "First CNP app",
    "version": "1.0",
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "3.x"
    }
}
```

However on changing the version from `1.0` to `0.0.1` it is working correctly.

I am new to node so I thought this version refers to the app version so I can give this any number. Please let me know what actually it is referring to and about the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can link-hop from the [package.json](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/json.html#version) documentation to the [node-semver](https://github.com/isaacs/node-semver) doc to http://semver.org/, but the gist is, valid version strings must have a MAJOR version, a MINOR version, and a PATCH version:

```
major.minor.patch
```

So `1.0` is not valid because it doesn't have a patch version.  `1.0.0` would be acceptable.